# Displaying single Item from Database in django

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to display single item by my choice. is there a way we can display a single item?
Right now I am displaying all items using for loop.
Here is my code for all items.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Task(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
from .models import *
from .forms import *


def index2(request):
tasks = Task.objects.all()
context = {'tasks': tasks}
return render(request, 'task/index2.html', context)
```

Index2.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Home</title>
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%  static '/css/style2.css' %}" />
 </head>
 <body>

{% for task in tasks %}
{{task}}
{% endfor %}

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look into what `Task.objects.all()` is doing.

Comment: It displaying all the object i have. I want to display products individually but not by their name.  Just like we get elements by index in array.

Comment: I was trying to give you a hint. Anyways, I think what you want is `Task.objects.get()` [More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get). Let's say object 1 has id=1. You can get an object by their attributes values.

Answer (score 0):

if by displaying single item you mean showing the item based on its specific attribute you can use specific querysets

```
tasks = Task.objects.get(title=title_name) //gets the task whose title is title_name
```

or

`tasks = Task.objects.filter(complete=false) //gets all those which is yet to be finished`

some examples -> https://www.programink.com/django-tutorial/django-queryset.html

Comment: Let suppose I have 4 items in my database. 
I want to display all items individually.
Just like in array we get elements by index[0].
So is there any way we can display items individually using index or any other method but not by their name
Thanks